# Dataloader to MySQL with SSL

Tags: data-loader, ssl

Have scripted a salesforce dataloader import job using cliq with a MySQL source.
see http://code.google.com/p/dataloadercliq/wiki/CLIqWithMySQL

Everything works correctly..  Yet I am required to use SSL to encrypt the MySQL communication.

My understanding is that one would need to provide additional properties to the database-conf.xml file.  Found the following docs which detail how to connect to MySQL using SSL. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html

The document point to setting a property called useSSL.

If one specifies in database-conf.xml

```
<property name="useSSL" value="true"/>
```

You get the following message -

> 'useSSL' is not writable or has an invalid setter method.

Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Has anyone successful got the jdbc driver to work with SSL.  If so can you please point me in the direction on how to configure it.  Can connect directly to the server through a client tool using SSL, so I have to believe I am not configuring the jdbc driver correctly.  Working on a windows server..

Thank you for reading and responding!!